# Rich formatting not working

Tags: bug, status-norepro

On StackOverflow the rich formatting bar disappeared. I tried refreshing my cache but that did not work. It works fine on meta.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Browser/Operating system?

Comment: windows xp, firefox 3.5. it appeared 3 or 4 hours ago

Comment: "3 or 4 hours ago".  Is it okay now, or do you still have the problem?

Comment: You can never format Rich!

Comment: I still have the problem. I tried in IE7 and it breaks as well. Cleared the cache again and still nothing

Comment: Does it work using Firefox' Safe Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came back suddently today with no intervention on my end. It wasn't working yesterday and it got back up today after the night. I have no clue of what happened

Answer (score 0):

Do you have NoScript installed? The formatting bar disappears for me if I block sstatic.net

Comment: No. I have firebug and stylish (but no styles defined and I had it for a while now)

Answer (score 0):

No other reports of this from any other users.

I see you've tried this in both IE and Firefox.

Are you behind a proxy / firewall that is blocking sstatic.net or otherwise interfering with normal HTTP traffic?

Comment: No proxy, no firewall aside the windows firewall but it shouldn't block things like that. I'll try this from home tonight to see if that's my user or my machine